# отсутствие файлов в devtools

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-devtools

подскажите пожалуйста, как исправить ошибку.
Хотел сделать фоновое изображение для секции на сайте. При проверке картинка не отображается. Оказалось, что в devtools не отображаются некоторые папки по сайту (в том числе и картинки).
Изображение подключал через css
background-image: url("../05_layout-html/img/СпецПредложение.jpg");
если же делать через img непосредственно через html, то картинка грузится
Объясните , пожалуйста, в чем дело

Comment: Не верно указан путь? HTML и CSS файлы в разных директориях лежат?